# Single criteria query with two separate sets of restrictions

Tags: hibernate

I'm wondering if you can create a single criteria query then somehow create two separate sets of restrictions with two completely different sets of results without having to issue a second query?

Comment: if you find an equivalent for NHibernate's `.Future()` then yes

Comment: @Firo, I'm not sure I understand your answer.

Comment: .NET's port of Hibernate NHibernate has a feature which does batch queries, but i do not know if there is an equivalent feature in hibernate, too. It's just ab keyword which may be helpful for searching